# Are spreadsheet formulas on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been closing questions tagged [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) that seem like "how do I do this in Excel?".

Is that appropriate?

Here is a short list recent of ones that I feel are off-topic.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472302/populating-a-tab-with-a-subset-of-data-from-another-tab-based-on-a-variable-in-a
- [Excel formula with times in 1904 date system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464803/excel-formula-with-times-in-1904-date-system)
- [Formula to deliver answer that is in another sheet, to the left of a matched cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445633/formula-to-deliver-answer-that-is-in-another-sheet-to-the-left-of-a-matched-cel)
- [Stripping file extensions from file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440886/stripping-cell-values-in-excel)

Comment: VBA is a form of programming.  If the answer is a formula or VBA code and not a series of shortcuts, I'd say it counts.  If its a how to use the app question, I'd say close it.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not referring to VA but the front end of Excel.

Comment: It's a small step from this to "how do I calculate a median with Windows Calculator?"

Comment: On what grounds do you think they should be closed? Do you also think questions on SSRS formulas [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24459212/73226) should be closed?

Comment: @MartinSmith that's a flavor of vb

Comment: I don't see that it is any more VB like than Excel formulas syntax wise or why that is relevant anyway. The following is valid excel formula syntax (though maybe not semantically) `=IF(A5=MID(TODAY(),1,9),1,0)`. Compare that with the reporting services example of `=IIF(Fields!Closed_Date = Mid(Today(),1,9), "1", "0")`

Comment: [Excel is turing-complete](http://boingboing.net/2013/09/20/implementing-a-turing-machine.html), so I guess it's a legit programming language that should be on-topic here

Comment: Excel is programming -- don't close them.

Comment: I've written some insanely complex logic in Excel formulas. This is programming (in a rather awkward language :-) and IMO they should not be closed.

Comment: `"excel-formulas"` tag therefore is in my ignored tags list and I will not be answering any of those now or in the future. Formulas are easy enough and there is plenty of help on them on the internet so anyone seeking help has got plenty of resources on the internet - go do your search and research and solve your problem yourself.

Comment: [Another answer from Joel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110909) worth checking out

Comment: similar issue is happening with the google spreadsheet tags

Comment: [The top-users in the excel-formula tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel-formula/topusers) should justify whether the questions are on/off topic

Comment: @mehow thats a nice page - look how many are unanswered!

Comment: @DanielA.White They are unanswered because they are unclear/off-topic and there are not enough people participating in the tag to vote close them...Sad but true.

Comment: @mehow - Joel's answer is simply discussing the use of the `excel-vba` tag. It doesn't mention the ontopic-ness of formulas anywhere. The answer you pointed out by retailcoder is frankly irrelevant. Why should we pay more attention to that +4 answer than the +73 one on this page?

Comment: Excel formulas are a form of 'programming a worksheet' and the tags description should reflect that. However, if a user is asking a question about 'how do I sum a column of numbers' that belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) or some other site in the Excel-based Internet-verse. I personally draw the line in the sand where they are trying to accomplish something that no office flunkie would have a clue on how to achieve **BUT** they have tried **AND** they show their attempt.

Comment: [tag:excel-formula] should be burned. It has no place a long with [*-vba] as well. If anything it should be excel formula and [*-vba] should most likely be * [tag:object-model].

Comment: [Just going to leave this here](http://dilbert.com/strip/1997-09-10)

Answer (score 141):

I don't think we should close these. Especially if they're specifically about writing excel formulas.

What programming is is very hard to define. Even if we attempt to - a lot of people consider HTML programming and a lot don't, same for CSS and so on yet those are clearly on topic here.

For example - here is a classic problem, Euclid's algorithm [coded in Excel](https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/quenell/s2002/ma319/demos/euclid.html).

These questions are after all about composing commands on top of each other to take the given input and transform it to an output. Even if it wasn't turing complete like Yogu said - I think we should allow them.

To make this perfectly clear - questions about how to use the excel program itself like "How do I open a file" do *not* fall under this category.

Comment: I agree, I'd still like to reference Wikipedia's definition of a programming language: "A programming language is a formal constructed language designed to communicate instructions to a machine, particularly a computer. Programming languages can be used to create programs to control the behavior of a machine or to express algorithms.". That being said, people have to remember what HTML stands for; HyperText Markup Language. HTML is a markup-language, not a programming-language. The name it-self should be enough, if not then the definition helps. -- But again, I agree with you.

Comment: An added reason why I view them to be on-topic is because the answer to some Excel questions is to use VB in the code-behind, which is definitely on-topic here :)

Comment: If I may add a remark, I recently discovered (i'm not a huge excel user) that function names to be used in formula's are localized. This is the only programming language I know that does that. Wouldn't that be an issue that someone can provide a perfectly good answer that may not work on the OP's computer because of that ?

Comment: Say you are a VBA developer with 15 years in the business -> now go follow the VBA tag on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Hmm, writing my CV is "to take the given input and transform it to an output" in the sense that it turns bullsh*t into a job :-) But I don't think we should allow questions about CVs.

Comment: HTML is an important part of front-end development. How many web application users do you know, who can create a valid HTML document without help of IT employees? But the Excel is generally used software, and formula creation is a common action for Excel users.

Comment: Another example: [Webscraping YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665). While the question itself is gimme teh codez question(which is not off topic btw), would it be programming, only if it is done through [tag:selenium] or another language?

Comment: The link in this answer is broken and I can't suggest an edit, but I infer OP pointed to something like [this](http://users.bestweb.net/~quenell/s2002/ma319/demos/euclid.html) if they want to edit it in.

Answer (score 56):

Excel formulas (like scripting questions) inhabit the grey, fuzzy area between Stack Overflow and Super User. Question on these can be asked on either site and *should not* be migrated unless at the express wish of the OP.

As there is overlap between Stack Exchange sites this means that just because a question is on topic on site B doesn't necessarily make it off topic on site A.

Obviously this overlap is limited so you should double check when you encounter a question about Excel to make sure that it's about what you think it's about.

Comment: There isn't much overlap though in terms of expertise - VBA questions in particular wither on the vine at SU.

Answer (score 18):

I'd like to mention Wikipedia's [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) of a programming language:

> A programming language is a formal constructed language designed to communicate instructions to a machine, particularly a computer. Programming languages can be used to create programs to control the behavior of a machine or to express algorithms.

This is more or less what we're taught in computer science.

That being said, if you can achieve these communications in one way or another, using a programming-language, then you're programming.

You can program in Excel. If the questions are about the Excel formulas, then they should stay. If the questions are about achieving some functionality provided by the user-interface then it should, in most cases, be removed.

Comment: According to the definition the English is a programming languages for Siri, Cortana and Google Assistant. Is it programming to ask Siri to perform a task?

Comment: @Alexander No, that’s interacting with a program using its VUI (Voice User Interface)

Comment: @agrm, Excel formulas are written via interaction with Excel spreadsheet user interface. I create a web-application through IDE interface. Your keyboard is an interface. So it's not relevant criteria for programming.

Answer (score 17):

If they have a formula that doesn't quite work the way they want it to, and they're looking for help on how to modify/fix it, then that's probably on-topic.

If they have a requirement and they want you to write a formula for them (or have logic in some other language that needs a transcode), that's the same as any other programming question where they haven't put in any effort.

Using that criteria, I would close the 1st and 4th question on your list, the 3rd looks fine to me, and the 2nd looks salvageable, but he has to show his work first.

Answer (score 13):

While the programming definition may be grey as to whether Excel formula are programming, stepping outside of SO:

- The online Excel community typically splits forums into *programming (read VBA)* and *formulae*. In some cases the forums specifically are `VBA` only.
- Every day users of Excel in the business or home environment don't refer to themselves as programming when using Excel "normally".

While I normally vote to close vanilla Excel formula questions on SO, I accept there are different views on this, and it is a matter of preference.

The bigger issue is raised by [pnuts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts) in a comment above - why are there `VBA` questions on SuperUser?

Interestingly while SO Excel formula question often get migrated to SU, the SU moderators don't accept suggestions that clear cut programming questions should be migrated to SO - which is a net loss for the askers as regardless of discussion semantics as to what constitutes programming, SO is actually where the heavy hitting Excel expertise is.

Comment: Spreadsheet formulas (the `=SUM(A1:A10) + B42` type thing) is functional programming with unoriginal names. Sans VBA, Excel formulas are more closely related to lisp than any thing else.  Related reading: [Spreadsheet Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.151.6540&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for the link. I've read many of the EUSPRIG papers - interesting stuff.

Comment: @user289086 , if Excel formula writing is **spreadsheet programming**, then the document creation within MS World is **paper programming** or **printer programming**.

Answer (score 7):

I'd challenge anyone who thinks this is not programming to get 200 reps or so in [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) or [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula) and still have the same opinion they had before. Just because it has a GUI doesn't automatically make it off topic or not about programming.

Spreadsheets are basically data holders, specifically in a two dimensional array like format. Formula is just data manipulation.  Although the feature set is relatively low, at it's core, data manipulation using formula is similar to [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) or [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas).  I'll list some features of formula that are common in other programming languages:

- Data types: As with any typed programming language, all data have types like number, string, date. And there are problems with mixing types just like any other typed language.
- Data structure: Arrays, specifically 2D arrays are supported. Formulas are written to manipulate these arrays and output new arrays. These are called array-formulas.
- Inbuilt Functions:  These are comparable with inbuilt methods of any other language. A new function is just a nesting/combination of inbuilt functions just like in any other language.  For example, for `string`,  formulas exist for `join`,`split`, `find`, `replace`,  `unicode`, etc. Google sheets even supports [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and questions about it are [regularly asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+google-sheets). Are regular expressions mostly used by programmers or end users?
- Operators:  All commonly used operators(`+`,`-`,`&`,`AND`,`OR`, etc.) including bitwise operators(`BITOR`,`BITAND`, etc.) are supported.
- Conditional statements: `IF` and `SWITCH`(Switch...case) are supported.
- Loops: This is not robustly supported, but there is still some support for it in iterative calculations.
- HTTP GET requests can be made to a url(urlencoding functions supported) with `WEBSERVICE`(excel)/`IMPORT*`(Google sheets) formulas with the resulting data parsed with [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath), if needed. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064665) a sample Youtube webscraper built with formula.
- Google sheets specifically has formula support for a reduced version of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), called [google-query-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-query-language), where sql statements are sent to a range using formula. Questions about  this are [regularly asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-query-language). For eg, a recent question was *Why doesn't `LIKE`'s `%` match new lines with this query:* `=QUERY(B:G;"SELECT D, E, SUM(F), AVG(F) WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND B LIKE '%"&H1&"%' GROUP BY D,E pivot C")`.  Are queries like these used by non-programmers?

Data manipulation using functions/inbuilt methods is programming and cannot be considered off-topic, because it has a GUI or because the profession of it's intended audience is not  related to computer science.

If you still believe it's not a programming tool, I would ask you to take up the challenge and still say that this is similar to using a notepad or writing in a Word software and not a programming tool.

Answer (score -5):

The Stack Overflow Help Center [says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions about **general computing** hardware and **software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools **used primarily for programming**.

The MS Excel is a [part of MS Office](https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-all-microsoft-office-products). Who are users of the application? Is it primarily used by programmers? The Excel is generally used by

- Financial analysts
- Administrative assistants
- Retail store managers
- Project managers
- Business analysts
- Data journalists
- Accountants

I agree, there are many task in Excel that requires programming skills (connetion to such external sources as SQL Server, VBA coding or other features that are placed on Developer tab). But the main target audience of the application doesn't know anything about programming, so it is expected the user should solve such typical task as formulas writing without programming skills. A formula creation is a common daily task of an office clerk. **Formulas in cells are not used primarily for programming.**

So, my opinion is a question about MS Excel that doesn't require to use Excel Development tools or external data sources (i.e. the question could be solved by typical Excel user) is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The question that are mentioned in the original post, are solved without involving of tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: @pnuts , the topic about Excel formulas. Note, the main part of my answers about manipulation of HTML using JavaScript or server-side engine. Moreover, the HTML requires special knowledge. Do you know many users that can to create valid HTML?

Comment: @pnuts, the Excel is a powerful tool that allows to generate, process, analyze and represent data. While the question "How to set formula through VBA?" is on topic, a Excel formula by itself is not used primarily by programmers or for programming.

Comment: @pnuts, do you really believe that Excel formulas are used for software development or maintenance? Ok, what's language used in Excel formulas? Is it OOP or FP or markup?

Comment: *Generally*, a question about how to write an Excel formula isn't a question about Excel, it's a question about the programming language that Excel implements for its formulas. Just like how the question "Why do I get a `NameError` from this Python code?" is a question about the Python programming language - not about `python.exe`. The "unless" part there is, to my understanding, primarily intended to include questions about how to use IDEs (which I personally oppose, but eh).

Answer (score -6):

Having just had one of my questions on Excel apparently deleted, I don't agree at all. Excel formulae are a form of programming, which not all people with technical skills will be familiar with. I'm a web developer, with only moderate Excel skills.

One of the fastest ways for people like myself to learn is to view other examples, so even questions like mine (which may appear basic and simple to those with the knowledge), are valid ones and helpful to the section of the community I come under.

If you don't like a question, move on. That's my thought on the subject.

Answer (score -10):

Questions about Excel formulae are on topic at [SuperUser.Com](http://superuser.com). They should be migrated there.

This is a long-standing practice. [One of my first SO questions](https://superuser.com/questions/139449/using-excel-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-cells-in-a-column-containing-the-text) was about an issue I encountered with Excel.

Comment: At the time I posted that question, I thought that SO _was_ the right place for it.

Answer (score -11):

Something an average user of Excel should know should not be on topic here, which includes formulas.  This is a site for professional developers to help each other, not support for end users.  This kind of question lowers the value of SO and should be moved to SU.  [List weekday dates with certain dates excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885512/list-weekday-dates-with-certain-dates-excluded-in-google-docs-sheets)

Comment: So something the "average" "user" of java should know is not on topic then?

Comment: @chancea Average users would not likely know Java.  By average user, that would be not a profession / hobbyist programmer, but it would include someone working in a financial office that uses excel.

Comment: let me back up a bit here, are you specifically referring to the linked question or are you saying _all formulas_ of excel?  The way I interpreted your answer was "_all formulas_ are off-topic"

Comment: @chancea the linked question is a good example of what I think should be off topic, but all formulas are built in functionality of Excel.  It'd be the same as asking how to bold in Word or make a chart. I think VBA should be on topic as that is programming and beyond what an average user would utilize, but there are a number of Excel and Google sheets questions on SO where the answer is simply "use this formula".  Those I think are more appropriate on SU.