# The "Other" option for voting to close is in the wrong place

Tags: feature-request

In my opinion it is wrong to force a choice between:

•  duplicate
•   off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.
•   unclear what you're asking
•   too broad
•   primarily opinion-based

*before* allowing access to:

Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong).

The help center does not define much at all, just provides some guidance (which is fine by me) and, as probably everyone is well aware, even something as fundamental as “programming” continues to be debated (eg [Are Excel formulas on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic)).

There have been many questions that just don’t seem appropriate for SO (perhaps licensing, monetisation, proprietary code and such like) that fit the first four general bullet points at [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and that are not specifically ruled out by the six numbered special cases there.

An example (from 2010) that I have just noticed is of **timing**. Clearly on topic when asked (though I accept it probably would not be according to current guidelines) its value has completely evaporated over the interval since it was asked.

That question has just been closed with the highly inaccurate banner

> “*Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.*"

given that it was about a specific library’s ability to read a very small number of versions of a specific application.

For that example I think closure was the right decision (I voted for closure) but the stated reason is **wrong** though virtually the only choice. I did choose a custom reason “*because time has superseded it. It is discussed here where "from a time of different standards" (@bmargulies) was mentioned and that it is now obsolete.*” which I think is ’near enough’ **right** but to get to the point of being able to give that reason I had to go via not “within the scope defined in the help center” and as far as I can see the scope in the help center makes no mention of (amongst other matters) obsolescence.

Unless the help center deals with these exceptions more comprehensively the simplest ‘fix’ would seem to be to move the “Other” option up one screen. Please consider doing so.

BTW 'Up one screen' would be to a level on a par with the likes of "**duplicate of...**", so not predominant.

Comment: It's not a *bug* unless it's not working as intended or designed. Since this is *exactly as designed*, it can't be classified as a *bug*. Perhaps you can retag as a feature request?

Comment: Key words: *mistake, malfunction, or programming error*. There's no mistake - the position was deliberately chosen, and it appears at that position. There's no malfunction - it works as intended. There's no programming error - it works as intended. Ergo, no "bug". Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well...no.  It doesn't make sense to make "Other" predominant.

There are several specific reasons why a question isn't on topic at SO:

- It's been asked before, and has a really good answer to it.  Any other answers to it would sound like rehashes of the same old thing.  I mean, if I had a dime for every `NullPointerException` question I've seen...
- It's asking something that simply doesn't fit here, like...

  - installing software on their platform
  - setting up professional servers (they have their own site for that)
  - looking for a library to do "X" - whatever that is, there's a **lot** of libraries out there
  - posting a whole smattering of code, saying "it's broken plz fix", and not telling us what "unbroken" even means to that snippet
  - a typo or some mistake that doesn't seem to be reproducible on anyone's machine with the same code
  - a question that's completely off-topic but one of our fellow network sites has agreed to allow us to migrate (there's a story behind this, believe me...)
- It's just... *unclear* as to what is is they're asking about.
- It's too broad to even approach (think "How do I build a forum?").
- There's a lot of opinionated discussion that could arise from this question which isn't constructive for the main site.

If the question is still off topic and doesn't fit into any of the above categories, **then** you should use "Other".

Here's my recommendation:  if you're curious about how to approach a question and questions like it in the future, **ask**.  That's what Meta is for.  Note also that the policy of what is and isn't acceptable changes, which is why the question from 2010 might not work now.

Comment: At the very least, it's "too broad" - if anyone would know the answer to "news" on the development, it'd be the library maintainers.  It would also qualify as a library witch hunt - the question doesn't stick to just one library.

Comment: It could also be "never" or "when the developer has time".  That's the thing; there's too many ways to answer the question directly.  Even so, that library may have fallen out of maintenance, and the canonical answer would be, "Use a different library, like this one", and you get everyone chipping in their favorite library to solve this  issue.  Too broad feels better than "general computing software/hardware" to me on this one.