# Gray area: Not about programming but material that is peripheral to programming

Tags: discussion

I am unclear about the boundaries of "off-topic". An example of what seems to me to be a gray area is [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907465/weka-gui-training-and-test-set-only-with-same-number-of-instances-to-be-compat) with the WEKA tag.  The title clearly identifies that the user is using the GUI, not programming using the WEKA libraries. Yet,  if you were programming using the libraries,  you might have this problem. The question is about how WEKA works.

Is this off-topic or not?  Can you offer some guidance for defining the boundary?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting gray area. You might want to edit the title of your question to something more general, so that it becomes meaningful for those of us who are unfamiliar with WEKA.

Comment: The key question is: Is WEKA a tool *software tool commonly used by programmers* or is the issue at hand *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*. If either of those is yes, the question is on-topic. If it has a gui and an API to do things is irrelevant.

Comment: One Issue I have with this is the Q is not self contained.  If those links break then the Q is dead.  If the answers have to upload stuff as well to work and those links break then the answers die too.  IMHO It does not look like a good fit for our site.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand your objection and have no disagreement with your comment.  However,  Suppose the user had provided real data. My question remains. This is not really a programming question, but would strongly affect programmers.  Is it OK?

Comment: @rene I think that the answer to your question 2 is definitely no. Question 1 is less clear to me. WEKA __is__ a software tool commonly used by programmers. It is a library of data analysis functions that can be accessed either through an API or through a GUI and direct user interaction.

Comment: It smells a bit as the Excel formula discussion. I'm not sure if that is fully settled yet.

Comment: @rene  Yes!  I think it is very similar.  I did not know about that discussion (pretty new here).  I will take some time and read it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Link for others [Excel Formula Discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic)

Comment: At first glance, Weka seems like scikit-learn, a library of algorithms and data structures that relies on another language for assembling the algorithms together (Weka uses Java, scikit-learn uses Python).  Questions about using the Weka library from code seem on-topic. Some questions about using Weka through it's GUI also seem on-topic if the underlying question is about an algorithm or data structure, and the GUI is just being used to rule out stupid typo bugs and to provide an MCVE. Questions about machine learning strategy might not get great answers here.

Comment: Just a heads up on terminology: What you link to is what most on SO term a post in the WEKA **tag**, not forum. "Forum" is kind of a bad word here, mostly because what SO tries hard to be is *not* what you typically see in many online fora (namely, discussions, lots of  back and forth, putting "[SOLVED]" in the title, etc.). Not a big deal, but something to watch out for.

Comment: @rene It's not *"or"*, it's *"and"*, isn't it? *"software tools commonly used by programmers; **and** is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* - E.g. PuTTY is a *"software tool commonly used by programmers"*, yet questions about connecting to SSH server with PuTTY are not *"unique to software development"*, so they are off-topic.

Comment: At the time of writing, I am impressed by the maturity of the meta effect on that WEKA question.