# Why is this question about shell programming closed as "not about programming or software development"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

[How to stop a uboot macro using itest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163346/uboot-stopping-a-macro-using-itest) was closed as "not about programming or software development"?

Aren't shell programming languages like Bash or in this case [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) CLI in the scope of Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm stumped how this isn't about programming, but the question might need more focus - it seems to ask about 2-3 separate things (step 2, "compound statement in the if/else/endif clause", "an "abort macro" step in one of those clauses").

Comment: This is gunna be one of those subjects everyone disagrees on.  IMO, this question is _not_ about programming. There is a line between using shell commands and actually doing shell scripting/programming. Just like there's a difference between using basic excel formulae, and effectively programming in them. Unfortunately the line here is more like a thick grey blur; where one shell question might be off-topic, another might be on-topic.

Comment: @Nickistired that particular question does look like programming to me. It's basically asking about how to conditionally exit a script. It's not about just running a single command.

Comment: Something to be aware of: the "not about programming or software development" close reason is displayed both when a majority of close votes choose that reason and sometimes when there is no majority reason (i.e. when the three votes cited different reasons). I do not know how to tell the difference without asking the people who voted to close (or asking someone who peeked at the votes after two were cast).

Comment: Ending in the open-ended "Suggestions?" does not help it. It is trivially transformable, so it doesn't *appear* to be too broad. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Comment: Unfortunately in my eyes you're a victim of a choice made long ago to allow questions on Stack Overflow which are only tangibly related to programming and thus have a far higher chance of spawning questions which are either off-topic or on the line, and thus you're subjected to people's personal opinions with really random results. A hard problem to solve now. just keep it in mind for the future. This is going to happen again.

Comment: @Gimby tangibly -> tangentially?

Answer (score 37):

First: questions are very rarely actually *about* a programming language. Maybe if you're wondering about the history of the language's development, or a justification for a design decision the language makes. But those questions are often off-topic because they lack *practical* value.

Rather, practical programming questions are generally about *the task*. Therefore, **the idea that "questions about X language/technology are inherently on/off topic" is a red herring**.

For shell languages, there is a pretty well established principle: **if you are using the language *to write a script*** - if you create a `.sh` file or type in a function in Bash to use later or edit such functions into a `.bashrc` etc. file, so as to record actions to take and perform automation - then you are scripting, and therefore programming, and therefore have a programming question, which is therefore **on topic**.

If, on the other hand, you are simply **using a command line to input commands one at a time, then you do not have a programming question** and the question is off topic. In this case you are simply using the computer in an ordinary manner as designed by the operating system authors. Even if such commands are nominally part of a "shell language", you are not actually using them to automate any future process. The question in this case should instead be asked on https://superuser.com, https://apple.stackexchange.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com as appropriate.

Similarly: we [do accept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875) questions about using a formula in a spreadsheet, since they're fundamentally about a process that's used to calculate a result, and about creating instructions for that process rather than doing the calculation oneself. We would not accept questions about the UI of a spreadsheet program, since that's simply about using a program used by ordinary computer users, in an ordinary way.

In this case: I have to admit that I've never heard of U-Boot before, and hadn't even considered that a bootloader might be designed to run user scripts. However, there is a tag there with over a thousand questions (and it even has well-received questions from within the last year, so this clearly isn't just an artifact of the attitude towards topicality changing over time); and this question describes an intent to write a "macro" (definitely a programming concept) which implements a multiple-step process using conditional logic expressed in statements; and the clear purpose is to **implement some logic which is repeatedly, automatically followed** by some other program or tool (i.e., this is clearly an attempt to *script* it).

**So this is definitely a programming question, and I cast the last reopen vote.**

Further, since the question is definitely asking about just one step in that multi-step process, and it's a how-to question (rather than asking people to debug code that isn't shown), I can't see another good reason to re-close it.

That said, I think the question *would definitely be improved* by framing it in terms of a code sample - because it would be more readily obvious that you are trying to write code, and because it would be easier to understand what exactly it is that you're missing. The question claims "I don't know how to create a compound statement in the if/else/endif clause"; but this implies knowing how to create such a clause in the macro language (which in turn implies that this is possible). It would be easier to follow if we saw a code sample which does this, and a description of a problem either with specifying an adequate condition, or with making more than one thing happen when the condition is met, or whatever it is exactly that's the sticking point. (While this was unclear to me, I suspect that has more to do with my unfamiliarity with the system, rather than the explanation.)

Comment: *If, on the other hand, you are simply using a command line to input commands one at a time, then you do not have a programming question and the question is off topic.* That feels like splitting hairs. Wouldn't syntax related questions of any other language be on-topic? I don't know why this specific exception is only made for shell language? Also, how exactly would this difference be enforced? If I wanted to ask about say `cp`, what's stopping me from just saying that this is used inside a .sh file or just put a dummy loop to prove "automation"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this distinction(IMO, without a difference) is discussed before and there was this consensus. But if someone could point out some relevant links, that'd be  helpful in increasing the depth of the conversation.

Comment: @TheMaster: If you're asking about how to use the `cp` utility -- like which flag to use to not copy symlinks -- it's not a programming question. If you're asking why `cp` fails sometimes when you pass a variable as an argument, or how to check the return value of `cp`, then those are programming questions. The difference? In the latter case, replacing `cp` by `rm` (or other) wouldn't meaningfully change the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Then again, if you ask about how to use Python's `shutil.copyfile` or Node's `fs.copyFile` both would be on topic again, making it somewhat arbitrary that just because a user could directly invoke `cp` from the terminal directly it it would be different. I mean, there is definitely a historic difference on how it was originally intended to be used, but that's not really relevant when judging the present day.

Comment: This kind of pointless distinction contributes to the overall toxicity of SO in general.

Comment: @Phil I don't see why or how. If you think it's "toxic" to insist that people put questions in the right place - then how do you expect to end up with an *organized, searchable* result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Phil is saying the distinction is pointless and therefore the end result is neither *organized* nor *searchable*.  It's unreasonable to expect a opinion of a powerful small minority to be followed by *people* or be punished by  that minority.

Comment: @TheMaster totally agree, the system we have here makes it really hard to get help. Otherwise SO wouldn't lose as much traffic to ChatGPT and the like.

Comment: @oguzismail: It's a matter of philosophy I suppose. I ark from the olden days of SO, where the mission was clear: SO was to be a _curated_ Q&A site. The goal of SO -- before corporate takeover -- was that most people would never need to _ask_, because the questions would already be answered. With the corporate takeover... there's a bit of a discrepancy between the mission -- still the same AFAIK -- and the actions ("driving engagement"). Still, so far, SO remains a Q&A website, not an IRC chat.

Comment: @DavidMulder: True enough, yet there _are_ different communities, and different subsets of expertise. If the question is about `cp` precisely, the crowd at Super User is probably better versed in its subtleties. If the question is about shell scripting, there's an expertise split between Super User & SO. If the question is about NodeJS scripting, the crowd at SO is probably more expert. A user is better served by asking the questions where the experts are, and we (all) are better served by concentrating the knowledge in fewer places (with appropriate redirections).

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's precisely *because* I want a well-curated Q&A site that I disagree with stances like the one in this answer. If the details of how a shell command works are gonna tend to be relevant to scripting, IMO that's entirely enough to make questions about them on-topic. Requiring the question to *explicitly* indicate it's being asked in a programming context at best means requiring "this is for a script, honest!" which is pointless noise (like "this isn't homework" disclaimers) and at worst means adding a code dump and making the question less broadly applicable. Both results are bad!

Comment: @MarkAmery: I didn't understand this answer as mandating a disclaimer. For any question, _context_ tends to matter -- especially because there are regularly better ways to achieve the task altogether, or special considerations (such as TOCTOU) to pay attention to. For a script, it's _natural_ to present the script (and its goal) as part of the question to provide said context.

Comment: @Phil your definition of "toxicity" could use some work. Belittling people is toxic. Racism/sexism/anti-LGBTQA+ is toxic. Saying "I'm sorry we can't help you with your landscaping because this is a home appliance store" ***is not toxic***. If somebody tried that IRL at a bricks-and-mortar store we'd all laugh at them. But because this is the internet, or because it's free, or because both things involved using computers, or for whatever reason it's never the fault of the asker *who refused all the feedback the UI tried to give them about what's on topic here*, no no, it's because SO is "toxic"

Comment: @MarkAmery So, if `print("hello world")` worked at a cmd prompt, and it became ordinary for non-programmer Windows power users to do that, would "why doesn't typing `print(hello world)` at the DOS prompt work?" *become* a Python question, in your estimation?

Comment: @oguzismail Stack Overflow traffic going down is by and large a **good thing** for the site. It means, among other things, that people who misuse the site are going away. If their problems are solved by a ChatGPT model trained on SO data, and this means they don't flood the site with vague non-question debugging requests where the code has multiple issues that are separately addressed by common duplicates, **great!** We never wanted those questions in the first place.

Comment: @JaredSmith The analogy is wrong on so many levels. Who made you sellers/owners? Why are askers considered buyers? A new user/asker is a contributor to the site just like you. All are sellers. Furthermore the actual difference is pointless, whereas your analogy exalts the difference between them to the difference between landscaping and appliances store. It's toxic, because a small organized minority decided that they will shutdown by force, anyone who tries to sell a replacement part for a particular brand of machine, while replacement parts for all other brand of machines are allowed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I find it highly unlikely that the crowd at super user is better than the crowd at SO for `cp` related questions. If expertise matters, I'd rather ask at SO rather  than SU.

Comment: @TheMaster ok I think your critique of my analogy is a little nitpicky but lets clean it up anyway to nail this down: lets say that you have a local Linux users group that you are a part of. Everyone is a contributor to the group, there aren't, in *your* words, "the privileged". Some people in the group start discussing World of Warcraft because they are trying to get it to run on Linux. But over time the discussion morphs from "how to run WoW on Linux" to more general discussion about *playing* WoW. This takes up more and more of the meeting time. Now, there's nothing wrong with...

Comment: ...playing World of Warcraft, or talking about playing WoW and bonding over a shared hobby, ***but it also isn't toxic*** for the rest of the group to ask those folks to take their WoW discussion elsewhere to *stay on topic about using Linux*, i.e. the intended purpose of the meetup. They're even welcome to stay and talk about using Linux, just not take it over to turn it into a WoW meetup. And this is totally fair and **not** toxic *even if the WoW players are a majority of the group*.

Comment: Bad analogies aside... I think it's far more gray than this answer is insinuating. Yes, general CLI questions are off topic, but it's certainly possible to have a CLI question that is programmatic in nature rather than "How do i delete a file" that would be a useful addition to the knowledgebase for programmers. Just because the code isn't being saved in a script file doesn't mean it isn't a useful problem to solve and store the answer to.

Comment: So if I type `ls .. . | sort | comm -first .g - | randline -n 50 | while read f; do echo "fetching $f"; httpget -O -preserve -sslquiet https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/$f; sleep 10; done` interactively at the shell command line — which I did 5 minutes ago, this is not a made-up example — am I "programming", or just using the computer in an ordinary manner as designed by the operating system authors?  (You don't have to answer that, but my point is, for Unix shells, the distinction between "using" and "scripting" is super, super blurry.)

Comment: @SteveSummit The point is that if you typed that off the cuff and it didn't work, you would be expected to debug it by checking what happens at each point in the pipeline; and if you encountered a problem that *didn't* boil down to misunderstanding an individual command, you'd have an actual programming question. For example, if the problem were caused by one piece not understanding the text encoding used by another.

Comment: For what it's worth: on Codidact we made "code review" a separate section (using Codidact functionality) of the main Software site, and the kinds of questions that now appear on PLDI would be on topic there. But we still saw fit to make separate sites for Power Users (i.e. superuser) and Linux Systems (i.e. unix.SE).

Comment: @JaredSmith But consider big-box home-improvement stores like
Home Depot, which typically sell both appliances and gardening
supplies.  Now, suppose there's one, perverse Home Depot
franchiser who decides he's not going to sell gardening supplies.
He puts a nice little sign next to the door clearly stating "This
store has no gardening supplies".  Yet people constantly
walk in asking where the gardening supplies are, and the staff
have to constantly explain they're not here.  Why can't people
read the sign?  Why can't people understand the simple fact that
this store doesn't sell them?

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm sorry, I've lost you on this analogy. A Home Depot store is in a very real way implicitly labeled as selling gardening supplies, because every other Home Depot location sells gardening supplies, and lots of people have been to other Home Depot locations and know, generally, what to expect from one. Stack Overflow, on the other hand, is (mostly) not full of other non-programming questions; there is not that sort of precedent to base the assumption. (Note: I'm not expressing any opinion as to the merits of the argument here, in part because I'm struggling to follow the analogy.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Let's not kid ourselves. People using search engines to find answers are responsible for most of the traffic to SO. Of which only a fraction bother with creating an account and asking a new question. Now there's a better tool to do that and it eliminates the need for visiting SO. For a forum that runs on ad revenue, I don't think that's a good thing.

Comment: @RyanM The issue here is whether question X is a "programming" or a "non-programming" question.  The distinction this answer attempts to elucidate (and which, allegedly, SO consensus wants to enforce) is, I assert, almost as arbitrary and counterintuitive to the layman as that imposed by the hypothetical gardening-free Home Depot manager.  Non-SO-regulars have a different expectation of what a "programming question" is, and are apt to be frustrated by SO's peculiar rules and expectations.

Comment: You're right, the analogy is imperfect, because an expectation that
(a) SO has a looser definition of "programming" than it in fact does
is not as objectively justified as is the expectation that (b)
Home Depot sells gardening supplies.  But something like expectation (a) *is*
widespread among newbies, and a counterexpectation that newbies will
somehow properly educate themselves about SO's actual
distinctions is bound to lead to frustration for both newbies
and regulars.

Comment: @SteveSummit I don't think there's ever going to be a consensus about what SO is: that's a moving target. There will always be people who for whatever reason want to turn SO into a bad clone of Reddit or (God forbid) Quora. I'm fine with the never-ending argument about this, what irks me is the assumption of ill-will: like the folks who try to keep the site true to its original mission are somehow bad actors who have seized the reigns of power to enforce their will on the oppressed. It's for folks to disagree with the rules, but I'm tired of being labelled toxic for just trying to follow them.

Comment: @JaredSmith This quibble about whether something is a programming question or otherwise.  The people who care, care more about this than actually answering the question.  It is of no interest to some random Joe who doesn't understand or particularly care about the more subtle points in the rules, and speaking as occasionally that Joe, who has arrived via a search engine, to find an unanswered question unanswered because some pedant deemed it ever so slightly off topic, or a duplicate of some different question etc, is unhelpful in the extreme.  Might just as well use Reddit, GPT, quora, etc

Comment: Adults may disagree on whether the correct label for this is "toxicity", but regardless, it is an aspect of this family of sites that I personally find repulsive, and lowers the overall quality/utility of the site.

Comment: @Phil Some people use the rules as an excuse to be an asshole. That makes *them* toxic, not the *rules*. "Adults may disagree on whether the correct label for this is 'toxicity'" if I called you a Nazi we might disagree about the finer nuances of the meaning of that word but it would unquestionably be an insult saying you are a bad person (I'm not doing that btw, just using it as an example). If your goal is to persuade someone that what they are doing/thinking is wrong, insulting them is a poor way to change their mind.

Comment: "but regardless, it is an aspect of this family of sites that I personally find repulsive" ok, then go somewhere else that suits your preferences better, there's nothing wrong with that and the internet has something for everybody. What *is* wrong is the *assumption that your dislike indicates immorality on the part of the other*. To be clear, none of this is intended to be a defense of actually toxic behavior like sarcasm or "RTFM"ing. Like I said, assholes gonna find a way to be assholes. I like the well-tended curated garden of SO. Maybe you prefer the wilds of r/programming. Isn't that ok?

Comment: @JaredSmith I actually prefer SO or at least what it was meant to be.  I'd also prefer it if there were fewer assholes misusing the rules. I never called any person toxic, any more than you called me a nazi. I dislike the toxic behaviour that drags down the room, not the room itself.

Comment: I am sympathetic to both sides of the lengthy argument about "toxic" here. I think the idea Phil is trying to express - which English has no other single word for - is that the site is not merely unpleasant & harmful but *insidiously* so; that it looks safe & pleasant on the surface but hurts you once you are immersed in it. (Not endorsing this view, just pondering connotations of "toxic".) But the main mental association I have with "toxic" is "toxic waste"; calling a community toxic sounds a bit like calling its members poisonous human garbage, i.e. maximally insulting & dehumanising.